# Extract matched text and its neighboring context n words upstream n words downstream (nth occurrence from left and nth occurrence from right)

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I need text that fits nicely in an autocomplete dropdown. This required more strategy than it would initially appear. Using hidden text or fadeout option didn't work well because the matched text string was often outside of the visible frame of its context. The ellipsis approach currently is a bit heavier weight than I need. "Show more" works well, but not in the context of the dropdown box; I don't want the user to worry about anything except selection of the option. I just want a line or two of context centred around the matched token. There are some related answers, but nothing that quite addresses the need for both n from the right and n from the left.

```
var haystack = "r4 r3 r2 r1 needle r1 r2 r3";
var needle = "needle";
var delim = " ";
var numWords = 5;
var trimmedText = trimToNeighboringText(haystack, needle, numWords, delim);

console.log("With " + numWords + " neighboring words: \"" + trimmedText + "\"");
```

Comment: Can you please show us an example code with an example input and the wished output? Thanks.

Comment: Wow; didn't expect responses so soon :) I'm working on something now that nearly works. Will post it in 15 mins or so.

Comment: you may post it now.

Answer (score 1):

Regex can simplify this a lot!
Here is my solution:

```
var haystack = "L5 L4 L3 L2 L1 needle R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6",
    needle = "needle",
    numWords = 3;

var result = haystack.match("(?:\\s?(?:[\\w]+)\\s?){"+numWords+"}"+needle+"(?:\\s?(?:[\\w]+)\\s?){"+numWords+"}");

console.log("With " + numWords + " neighboring words: \"" + result[0] + "\"");
```

> *With 3 neighboring words: " L3 L2 L1 needle R1 R2 R3 "*

Comment: Brilliant! This is elegant and works under all the necessary scenarios. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var haystack = "L5 L4 L3 L2 L1 needle R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6";
var needle = "needle";
var delim = " ";
var numWords = 3;
var trimmedText = trimToNeighboringText(haystack, needle, numWords, delim);

console.log("With " + numWords + " neighboring words: \"" + trimmedText + "\"");

function trimToNeighboringText(haystack, needle, numWords, delim) {

    // number of delimiter occurrences to look for,
    // this assumes the same on both sides
    var numDelims = numWords + 1;

    // this splits on the text that is matched
    var tokens = haystack.split(needle);

    if (tokens.length > 1) {

        var leftEllipsis = "";
        var rightEllipsis = "";

        // Get the index of the start character within the left neighbor,
        // working backwards
        var startIndex = nthOccurrenceBackwards(tokens[0], delim, numDelims);
        //console.log(startIndex + ": " + tokens[0].substr(startIndex));

        // if text is truncated at left
        if (startIndex > 0) {
            leftEllipsis = "... ";
        }
        // if text is not truncated at left
        else startIndex = 0;

        // Get the index of the end character within the right neighbor
        // working forwards (note that start is local to right neighbor)
        var endIndex = nthOccurrenceForwards(tokens[1], delim, numDelims);

        // if text is truncated at right
        if (endIndex > 0) {
            rightEllipsis = " ...";
        }
        // if text is not truncated at right
        else {
            endIndex = tokens[1].length;
        }

        // Concatenate the left fragment, the needle, and the right fragment
        return (leftEllipsis + tokens[0].substr(startIndex) + needle
                             + tokens[1].substr(0, endIndex) + rightEllipsis);

    } else {
        console.warn("Match not found");
        return haystack;
    }
}

function nthOccurrenceForwards(str, pat, n) {
    if (str.length == 0) return 0;
    //console.log("\""+str+"\"");
    var i = -1;
    while (n-- && i++ < str.length) {
        i = str.indexOf(pat, i);
        if (i==-1) break;
        //console.log("n and i "+n + "," + i)
    }
    return i;
}

function nthOccurrenceBackwards(str, pat, n) {
    if (str.length == 0) return 0;
    var j = str.length;
    while (n-- && j-- > 1) {
        j = str.lastIndexOf(pat, j);
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: This covers scenarios in which the matched text is at the leftmost or rightmost extent of its context. It also accounts for the full extent of the surrounding text, even if that is less than the desired number of words; in this case it adds "...". There's an off by one error on the left at the moment which adds another (extra) space. It could also be adapted to fit scenarios in which you want neighboring text on either side of multiple occurrences of the matched text.